# Connecting Arduino wifi shield to Mbed Nucleo ST F401RE board

Tags: arduino, wifi, mbed

I would like to test WiFi connectivity on mbed board (Nucleo ST F401RE) using Arduino Wifi shield. Doe anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

In case you're interested there is a ESP8266 library for any mbed board with a UART port : [mbed ESP8266 Wifi Driver](https://developer.mbed.org/teams/esp8266/) .